# Heroku only error: undefined method `write_from_user' in Rails on Heroku, but everything works in dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, strong-parameters

The error occurs when I try to submit a form using strong parameters on a Heroku prod environment. The application log says the following:

```
2016-11-01T05:20:15.948227+00:00 app[web.1]: [7a7a60bf-b9bf-404d-890e-3692ba99bad0] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
2016-11-01T05:20:15.949267+00:00 app[web.1]: [7a7a60bf-b9bf-404d-890e-3692ba99bad0]   
2016-11-01T05:20:15.949316+00:00 app[web.1]: [7a7a60bf-b9bf-404d-890e-3692ba99bad0] NoMethodError (undefined method `write_from_user' for nil:NilClass):
2016-11-01T05:20:15.949353+00:00 app[web.1]: [7a7a60bf-b9bf-404d-890e-3692ba99bad0]   
2016-11-01T05:20:15.949490+00:00 app[web.1]: [7a7a60bf-b9bf-404d-890e-3692ba99bad0] app/controllers/gdrs_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

I'm using Rails5 in dev and prod with a postgres db. Everything works perfectly in dev. Is there a difference in the way Heroku passes url params?

Here's my code from the create action:

```
def create
  @des = Designer.where(email: Rails.application.secrets.design_lead_email)
  @gdr = Gdr.new(secure_params)
  @gdr[:uuid] = SecureRandom.hex(5)
  @gdr.designer = @des
  @gdr[:status] = "Queued"
  if @gdr.save!
    VisitorMailer.gdr_created_email(@gdr).deliver_now
    DesignerMailer.gdr_created_email(@gdr).deliver_now
    redirect_to gdr_url(@gdr[:uuid])
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

And the secure_params action:

```
private

def secure_params
    params.require(:gdr).permit(:uuid, :client_name, :email, :dept, :ext, :cost_centre, :activity_type, :project_name, :description, :size, :quantity, :colour, :quote, :rush, :rush_desc, :proof_date, :print_date, :delivery_instructions, :reprint, :old_gl, :server_path_to_files, :activity_code) 
end
```

I'm using Devise to create the Designer model.

Comment: can you please post create action from gdrs_controller

Comment: I've still been trying to track down the problem to no avail. Running in dev, with the same postgres database, everything works fine. When I try to create new ActiveRecord objects using Gdr.new(params), even via rails console, I get similar errors along the lines of "undefinied method 'write_from_user'. Is there any way of accessing more detailed postgres logs on heroku?

Comment: I have deleted and redeployed the app many times, run the migration again and again and it's always the same. When I try to create ActiveRecord relations via command line the Gdr.new(params) command only saves a few of the values. They're same ones each time, but there's no common factor between them (i.e. some of the ones that get saved are simple strings, others integers etc). What could be going on! This is insane!

Answer (score 0):

Seems your are trying to call `write_from_user` on `nil` `object`. Use something like this `your_object.try(: write_from_user)` to handle nil. It will be more clear if you can post your controller code.

Comment: Good point, I've added the code from the create controller too @Deepak

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error is caused by my secure_params method, but I can't work out why. It runs fine in dev on the same database.

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with the postgres database (which is different from the sqlite db used in dev). Not all the parameters are getting saved to the db as they should, there doesn't appear to be any rule about which values get saved, other than it's the same ones each time. Should I open a new thread for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! I realised that the create action was failing because I hadn't configured actionmailer properly. I think it was somehow crashing mid way through a ddatabas commit.

Lessons were learned. Global error logging is switched on now.